# Connecting to a external exchange server via linux/php?

Tags: php, linux, smtp

We have an SMTP relay available that we are using on windows servers.

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = email.relay.url
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

Works great.

We need to set this up on linux/php and I have always just point to the exchange server (and it has always worked - but maybe I was relying on another mod doing something) using...

```
[mail function]
; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path = email.relay.url
sendmail_from = my@company.com
```

I am troubleshooting this issue with the helpdesk and they have assured me that my server IP has access to use the email relay (exchange server).   Is there additional checks on my side that I can do to see what is going on?

Comment: You should leave `sendmail_path` unset and configure the local mail server to relay to your smarthost.